# Angular 6: append sub form group using .addControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form that is is split across components and thus I need to use the `.addControl` to get the form to all work together.

This is the form structure at the moment:

```
name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]],
address: this.ofb.group({
    addressLineOne: ['', Validators.required],
    addressLineTwo: ['', Validators.required],
    addressLineThree: [''],
    addressPostcode: ['', [Validators.required, OrgValidators.postcodeValidator]]
})
```

I have converted the fields to the `.addControl` syntax like so:

```
this.createOrganisationForm.addControl('name', new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]));
this.createOrganisationForm.addControl('addressLineOne', new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]));
this.createOrganisationForm.addControl('addressLineTwo', new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]));
this.createOrganisationForm.addControl('addressLineThree', new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]));
this.createOrganisationForm.addControl('addressPostcode', new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, OrgValidators.postcodeValidator]));
```

However, they seem to lose the group 'address'. I tried adding the address in an object like so:

```
 let addressGroup = {
  addressLineOne: ['', Validators.required],
  addressLineTwo: ['', Validators.required],
  addressLineThree: [''],
  addressPostcode: ['', [Validators.required, OrgValidators.postcodeValidator]]
 }
```

and then adding it in like so:

```
this.createOrganisationForm.addControl('address', addressGroup);
```

but I get the error:

> is not assignable to parameter of type 'AbstractControl'.

How do I add a group of controls to a parent control using the `.addControl` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Initialise your addressGroup with type `FormGroup` as mentioned below:

> let addressGroup = {

```
let addressGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because addressGroup object is not an instance of FormGroup class.

```
const addressGroup =  new FormGroup({
  addressLineOne: ['', Validators.required],
  ....
})
```